# Not able to define "var" in replace() method - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I am trying to use `var` in replace method. See below code,
I wanted to replace all "xyz" from myString.

```
var myString = "abc qwer xyz abc qwer xyz abc qwer xyz";
var myNewString = myString.replace(/xyz/g,"");
console.log(myNewString);
```

> **Output**: `abc qwer  abc qwer  abc qwer`

But when I define variable for "xyz" it is not recognizing it.

```
var myString = "abc qwer xyz abc qwer xyz abc qwer xyz";
var setWord = "xyz";
var myNewString = myString.replace(/setWord/g,"");
console.log(myNewString);
```

> **Output**: `abc qwer xyz abc qwer xyz abc qwer xyz`

Can anyone help me to understand why I am not able to define variable in replace method along with ***Regular Expression***.

Comment: `myString.replace(RegExp(setWord,'g'),"")`

Comment: Yes but I want to remove all "xyz", (setWord,"") will be remove only first instance.

Comment: This isn't an issue with the `.replace()` method, it's just that you're mixed up about how regular expression literals work.